# error posting data with curl and ssl

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I use this curl to post data:

```
$ch_request=curl_init();
            $curl =  curl_init();
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $request);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

            $response = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close ($curl);
```

But i check that the data isn't post, how can i know that? be cause i write it in a error_log, the system response with OK if the data was posted but i recive nothing when i check my error_log.

The URL that i try to post is generated automatically and is something like this:

```
https://precise-line.com/request?api_key=23894thfpoiq10f&user_id=508958644&delivery_type=Programado&route=Eje+1+norte&street_number=40&neighborhood=Centro&locality=Mexico&administrative_area_level_1=Distrito+Federal&postal_code=00650&country=Mexico&latlng=19.3596892%2C-99.2788723&destination-route=Calle+pinco+85%2C+Int.+1%2C+Col.+Florida%2C+Del.+%C3%81lvaro+Obreg%C3%B3n&destination-street_number=&destination-neighborhood=&destination-locality=Ciudad+de+M%C3%A9xico&destination-administrative_area_level=Distrito+Federal&destination-postal_code=01080&destination-country=Mexico&destination-latlng=19.3627808%2C-99.1757137&customer_email=ink_design%40hotmail.com&customer_phone=56581111&notification_email=&notes=Orden%3A+%2316652%2C+Cliente%3A+Said+Pe%C3%B1a+Amezcua%2C+Productos%3A+DEVIL+MAY+CRY+DEFINITIVE+EDITION+1%2C+&dispatch=True
```

This is how I generate my url:

```
$api_key=                                   '23894thfpoiq10f';
            $user_id=                                   '508958644';
            if ($shipping == $program){
                $delivery_type =    'Programado';
            }
            if ($shipping == $express){
                $delivery_type =    '99minutos';
            }
            $latlng =                                   '19.4165176%2C-99.1544438';
            $customer_email=                            urlencode($email);
            $destination_route=                         urlencode(implode(',' , array($address1,$address2)));
            $destination_locality=                      urlencode($city);
            $destination_administrative_area_level=     urlencode($province);
            $destination_postal_code=                   urlencode($zip);
            $d_latlng=                                  urlencode(implode(',', array($latitude,$longitude)));
            $customer_phone=                            urlencode($phone);
            $nombre =                                   'Cliente: '.implode(' ',array($first_name,$last_name));
            $orden =                                    'Orden: '.$name;
$request =  "https://precise-line.com/request?";
            $request.=  "api_key=".$api_key."&";
            $request.=  "user_id=".$user_id."&";
            $request.=  "delivery_type=".$delivery_type."&";
            $request.=  "route=Av+Cuauhtemoc&";"street_number=187&";
            $request.=  "neighborhood=Roma+Norte&";
            $request.=  "locality=Mexico&";
            $request.=  "administrative_area_level_1=Distrito+Federal&";
            $request.=  "postal_code=06700&";
            $request.=  "country=Mexico&";
            $request.=  "latlng=".$latlng."&";
            $request.=  "destination-route=".$destination_route."&";
            $request.=  "destination-street_number=&";
            $request.=  "destination-neighborhood=&";
            $request.=  "destination-locality=".$destination_locality."&";
            $request.=  "destination-administrative_area_level=".$destination_administrative_area_level."&";
            $request.=  "destination-postal_code=".$destination_postal_code."&";
            $request.=  "destination-country=Mexico&";
            $request.=  "destination-latlng=".$d_latlng."&";
            $request.=  "customer_email=".$customer_email."&";
            $request.=  "customer_phone=".$customer_phone."&";
            $request.=  "notification_email=&";
            $request.=  "notes=".$notes."&";
            $request.=  "dispatch=True";
```

Comment: Why don't you use Postman for testing APIs that you use. You'll know that if the request you're making is correct and also what response you are getting back. In your case I think you should do a GET request as your URL contains all the data.

Comment: yes, if i use Postman for test the URL the data is post, but without it i have not response!

Comment: So if you get proper response using Postman, click on generate code and see what curl options you are missing. That'll help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add 2 more options to curl:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
```

$params should be an associative array of the params you want like:

```
$params = array('api_key'=>'abcde')
```

Also, the value of `$request` in `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $request);` should be the base url without the params like `https://precise-line/request`

Comment: but some days ago the Curl that i post works, but since the last friday until now the cURL not work

Comment: if this solution fixed your issue, please accept the answer

Comment: Im sorry but  I saw that the solutiin was in other thing... It was in ssl version is 1 not 3 like my example!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and it was in the SSL version, i wrote 3 and the version to solved my problem is 1, but thank you for everyone who helps me